# How should a plugin register in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, plugins

Consider the following service

```
angular
    .module(moduleName, [])
    .service('myService', function () {
        this.plugins = [];

        this.process = function (data) {
            var output = data;
            this.plugins.forEach(function (plugin) {
                output = plugin.process(output);
            });
            return output;
    });
```

and a plugins

```
function doMagic() {
    ...
    this.process(data) { ... }
    ...
}
```

The idea I have is that when I load a plugin, it should be added to the `plugins` array. What would be the preferred way?

I can think of one way, and that would be to make a `service` of each plugin

```
angular
    .module(moduleName)
    .service('doMagicPlugin', function(myService) {
        myService.plugins.push( {
            ...
        });
```

But the problem I think here is that there is a lot of overhead, because a plugin will not be injected or used elsewhere.

Any feedback would be appreciated!

Comment: _"... there is a lot of overhead, because a plugin will not be injected or used elsewhere"_ Why is it "a lot" of overhead? Moreover the conclusion is not logical. It's not unusual for a service to be used in only one place.

Comment: Services are instantiated when they are injected. If you want to treat the service as a "global" singleton instantiate it in a `.run` block

Comment: I just noticed that my code will not work, because the service is never injected and thus never executed. So I guess this have to be inside a `run` block as suggested by @Daniel_L